# why only execute onreadystatechange once time?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to connect to a server to login, but when sending the request for verification, the state (statechange) remains in 1 (connection established) and then it is lost.
apparently the onreadystatechange only runs once, but I have no idea why, and investigated but the information I found was not my case.

```
var peticion
var net = {}
var strQuery

/* global XMLHttpRequest ActiveXObject */

window.onload = function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('comprobar')
  btn.addEventListener('click', validate)
  strQuery = 'login=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('login').value + '&nocache=' + Math.random())
}

function validate () {
  peticion = new net.CargarContenidos('http://localhost/Paginas/AJAXTest/servidor/compruebaDisponibilidad.php', mostrar, strQuery)
}

function mostrar () {
  console.log('si entro')
  console.log(peticion.req.responseText)
}

net.READY_STATE_UNINITIALIZAED = 0
net.READY_STATE_LOADING = 1
net.READY_STATE_LOADED = 2
net.READY_STATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
net.READY_STATE_COMPLETE = 4

net.CargarContenidos = function (url, funcion, data, funcionError) {
  this.url = url
  this.req = null
  this.onload = funcion
  this.onerror = this.defaultError
  this.cargaContenidosXML(url, data)
  console.log('finish')
}

net.CargarContenidos.prototype = {
  cargaContenidosXML: function (url, data) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      this.req = new XMLHttpRequest()
      console.log(this.req)
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      this.req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
    }
    if (this.req) {
      try {
        var loader = this
        this.req.onreadystatechange = function () {
          loader.onReadyState()
        }
        this.req.open('POST', url, true)
        this.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        this.req.send(data)
      } catch (err) {
        alert('error: ' + err)
      }
    }
  },

  onReadyState: function () {
    var req = this.req
    var ready = req.readyState
    console.log(ready)
    if (ready == net.READY_STATE_COMPLETE) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      var httpStatus = req.status
      if (httpStatus == 200 || httpStatus == 0) {
        this.onload()
      }
    }
  },
}
```

I am a student and I would really appreciate advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: no, it says absolutely nothing, neither the ide, nor the browser console

Comment: What is `comprobar` a button, submit button, etc?

Comment: its a <a> element

Comment: You should cancel its default action `function validate (event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: I have already canceled it but the problem persists 
and the network tab shows nothing, as if the request had not been made

Comment: thanks for help, I have solved the problem, apparently the headers should be passed directly to the query, instead of the constructor function, so the server didn't recognize the query, didn't execute the 'onreadystatechange' and it failed in silence